# not able to set limit for imput value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n, value,av,sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        sum+=value;
    }
    av=sum/n;

    if (av>=7.5)
    {
        cout<<"READY";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"NOT READY";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

how to set up limit for value entered such that it is greater than or equal to `0` and less than or equal to `10`. i tried do `while` and `if`, but then the ouptut is altered. pls help

Comment: Please show your attempt. Also please show the input, and the expected and actual output.

Comment: Sounds like you want to validate input, and ask again if it isn't OK. For that use a loop. You can put that in a function dedicated to the purpose.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
      cin >> value;

      while(value <0 or value >10)
       {
        cout << "please enter number in range of 0 to 10 only."
        cin >> value;
        if(value >=0 and value <=10)
        {
            break;
        }
      }
      sum+=value;
 }
```

Comment: Those `if` and `break` are not needed.

Comment: what happen if user enter first invalid value and then valid, in such case it will not come out from while loop.

Comment: That's what the `while` condition is for. The `if` checks the same thing unnecessarily.

Comment: Then how loop will break if user enter correct value.

Comment: On the next iteration of the loop it will check the condition and see that it's no longer true.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @interjay